# Getting category's custom attribute value

Tags: category

I have created a new tab in the category edit page that gives access to a custom category attribute that has a key of `mymodule_myattribute`. I did this using an install script:

```
$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_category',
    'mymodule_myattribute',
    array(
        'label' => 'My Attribute',
        'group' => 'My Attribute Tab',   //will be created if necessary
        'type'  => 'int',
        'class' => 'validate-number',
        'required' => false,
        'input_renderer' => 'mymodule/adminhtml_catalog_category_widget_mycoolwidget',
    )
);
```

The attribute appears in the new tab and the setting gets saved when `Save Category` is clicked. This is all good... however...I am trying to access that custom attribute value for each category in a stand alone script:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default'); 

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categories as $category) {

    $cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category->getId());
    var_dump($cat->getData('mymodule_myattribute')); // NULL
    var_dump($cat->getMymoduleMyattribute()); // NULL

    var_dump($cat->getName()); // My Cool Category Name

}
```

The above calls for the custom attributes return NULL even though I know it is getting saved (because Magento saves it for me).

Is there something blindingly obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: get function for getting values

Comment: Did you rebuild your indexes?

Comment: Boooosh .. no I hadn't re-indexed! Works now, thanks Marius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I programmatically updated my indexes (Thanks Marius):

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default'); 

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categories as $category) {

    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(5); $process->reindexAll();      
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(6); $process->reindexAll(); 

    $cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category->getId());
    var_dump($cat->getData('mymodule_myattribute')); // Gives result
    var_dump($cat->getMymoduleMyattribute()); // Gives result

    var_dump($cat->getName()); // My Cool Category Name

}
```